# Two-sided hitting time of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am trying to compute the hitting time of a linear Brownian motion on a two-sided boundary. More specifically, let $W_t$ be a (one-dimensional) Wiener process. Let $T = \inf \{t: |W_t| = a \}$ for some $ a > 0$. I want to find $\mathbb{P}\{ T > t\}$.

I know that probability distribution hitting time of a positive level, $\inf \, \{t: W_t = b\,, \  b > 0 \}$ can be computed quite easily, but I am not sure how to deal with it when dealing with the two-sided hitting time, i.e. with the absolute value. I am thinking of the minimum of hitting times of level $a$ and $-a$, but I can't get a promising conclusion.

Comment: Well, if $|W_t|=a$ then $W_t$ is equally likely to be $a$ or $-a$. I think that should let you use conditioning to finish, but when I did it I found that $P(T>t)=P(T_a>t)$, which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: This is equivalent to solving the heat equation on the space interval $[-a,a]$ with boundary conditions $P(x, 0)=1$ and $P(-a, t) = P(a, t) = 0$. I believe this gives a Fourier series solution with no nice closed form. [Notes on the heat equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolvingHeatEquation.aspx#PDE_HeatEqn_Soln1).

Comment: @BenDerrett Hi, could you please explain why this is true or give a hint? I can see that the density function of $W_t+x$ looks like the heat kernel, but I don't understand why this problem is equivalent to the heat equation with this boundary condition.

Comment: @syoung see http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/StochCalc2012/notes/Week4.pdf

Comment: @BenDerrett Thank you.

Comment: Two variants of the actual density of $T$ can be found in "Brownian motion and classical potential theory" by Port and Stone and in "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus" by Karatzas and Shreve

Answer (score 2):

I will give this a try.

For simplicity let $T_a=\inf \{t: |W_t| = a \}$

\begin{align}
Pr(|W(t)|>a)&=P(|W(t)|>a|T_a<t)Pr(T_a<t)+P(|W(t)|>a|T_a>t)Pr(T_a>t)\\
\end{align}

$P(|W(t)|>a|T_a>t)=0$ since the time that $|W(t)|$ hits $a$ for the first time has not arrived, hence $|W(t)|$ can not be bigger than $a$.

Also note that $P(|W(t)|>a|T_a<t)=\frac12+Pr(W(t)<-2a)$ since we know that $|W(t)|$ has hit $a$ before $t$ (we have $T_a<t$). Therefore the event $\{|W(t)|>a|T_a<t\}$ is equivalent to $\{|a+W(t)|>a\}$.

Thus $$Pr(T_a<t)=\frac{2P(W(t)>a)}{\frac12+P(W(t)<-2a)}.$$

Comment: Interesting. $\{|W(t)|>a|T_a<t\}$ is not an event.

Comment: @BenDerrett Many thanks for taking a look. It is even more interesting to me :-) why is it not an event?

Comment: I will leave the comment to Ben. What I see strange in your reasoning is when you that two events in the end are equivalent. Who tells you have all the time t to cross 2a? As Ben said that probability is expressed by a series

Comment: Many thanks. I will think of this more.

Comment: @Math-fun An [event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_%28probability_theory%29) is a set of outcomes to which a probability can be assigned. In particular, $\{|W(t)|>a\}$, $\{T_a\le t\}$ and $\{|W(t)|>a\text{ and } T_a\le t\}$ are events, but $\{|W(t)|>a| T_a\le t\}$ is not, since it doesn't refer to a particular set of outcomes.

Comment: @BenDerrett I think it defines an event: it is the event that $|W(.)|$ has hit $a$ at time $T_a$ before $t$ and at time $t$, $|W(t)|$ is above $a$.

Comment: @Math-fun That's the third event in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of hitting times for a Brownian Motion, $S$ starting at $0$ with barriers at $c$ and $-c$ and step size $l=1$ is given by

$$
P(T>x)=\left(1-\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^{i+1}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{(2i+1)c}{\sqrt{x}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{(2i-1)c}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right]\right),
$$
where $\Phi()$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

I am looking for a tidier representation myself [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309598/what-is-this-lognormal-like-distribution).

The proof comes from the reflection principle. The probability of the $S$ hitting the lower bound $-c$ ($c$) and returning back to the region $[-c,c]$ before time $x$ is equal to $S$ being in $[-3c,-c]$ ($[c,3c]$) region at time step $x$. For one sided boundary, this would be it. However, it is also possible for $S$ to hit $-c$, return back to $[-c,c]$ and then hit $c$. $S$ being in $[-3c,-c]\cup [c,3c]$ counts $S$ hitting both barriers twice. So, we need to take $S$ hitting both barriers separately.

The probability of $S$ hitting first $-c$ and hitting $c$ and then returning back to $[-c,c]$ is equal to $S$ being in $[-5c,-3c]$.

You can extend this approach to infinity to reach the correct distribution.