# What is this lognormal-like distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a distribution, marked with the blue line, which looks remarkably like a lognormal distribution.

[image: Distribution and possible lognormal approximation].

I used the median and mod values to get the mu and sigma values to estimate its lognormal counterpart. The resultant lognormal distribution is given with the orange line. Note that it is shifted slightly to the right to fit best to the distribution.

The distribution given by the blue line has the formula:

$$
dist(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(1-\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^{i+1}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{(2i+1)c}{\sqrt{x}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{(2i-1)c}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right]\right),
$$
where $\Phi()$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution and $c=50$ for this particular case.

The above equation is the probability of first incidence happening at $x=i$ to the boundaries $\{-c,c\}$ for a brownian motion starting at $0$.

My questions are:

- Is this a lognormal distribution? Would I get a better approximation if I use some other measures to get mu and sigma values, i.e., if I use variance and mean?
- If it is not a lognormal distribution, what it could be? I think I need something slightly more skewed.

Thanks in advance!

Appendix: Here is a python snippet to obtain the above formula.

```
#Performs the summation of the above CDF upto ss
from scipy.stats import norm
def cdf_of_dist(c,m,ss):
    aa=c/(m)**0.5
    P1=lambda s: ((-1)**(s+1))*(norm.cdf((2*s+1)*aa)-norm.cdf((2*s-1)*aa))
    res=1
    for i in range(ss):
        res+=P1(i)+P1(-i)
    return res-P1(0)
#Takes derivative of the CDF
def dist(c,ss):
    derivative_array=[0]
    for i in range(m-1):
        derivative_array.append(cdf_of_dist(c,i+1,ss)-cdf_of_dist(c,i,ss))
    return derivative_array
```

Comment: Without knowing how that distribution is obtained, we don't have much to say about it.

Comment: I included the formula and what that distribution means.

Comment: Your series has the form $-(\phi_3-\phi_1)+(\phi_5-\phi_3)-(\phi_7-\phi_5)+...$, therefore can be written in a simpler way $\phi_1+2 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i}\phi_{2i+1}$

Comment: I suspect that the sum actually runs over all integer $i$, i.e., $i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Anyway, I am very skeptical that the distribution reduces to any well-known one. Also note that, by employing a different method, the p.d.f can be computed by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ixs}}{\cosh(c\sqrt{2is})}\,\mathrm{d}s,$$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ in the above formula is the imaginary unit.

Comment: @SangchulLee How did you know? The code was written for summing over all integers but I miswrote it on Latex. That is very impressive! Also, which transformation is that?

Comment: what about computing variance, skewness and kurtosis ?

Comment: @C.Koca, My impression was that the formula came from applying reflection principle, so I thought that the sum should extend to both direction (i.e., reflection principle applied to both barriers). My formula is then the result of the inverse Laplace transform applied to $$\mathbb{E}[e^{-s (\tau_c \wedge \tau_{-c})}] = \frac{1}{\cosh(c\sqrt{2s})}. $$ (The above formula can be derived from the optional stopping theorem applied to a stopped exponential martingale of the Brownian motion.)

Comment: @GCab I included variance as well. Since calculations are limited to the data set (here, the first 30000 data points), I feel that variance can change but mod and median can be calculated perfectly. Still, the plots including variance are better for large $x$. Whatever two points I use, some of them are better for some purposes while some of them are the worse. Nothing fits perfectly.