# Distribution of hitting times for a Brownian Motion with two absorbing barriers and step size equal to 1

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, brownian-motion, random-walk

In the question " [What is this lognormal-like distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309598/what-is-this-lognormal-like-distribution) ", ck1987pd stated the formula for the probability distribution of hitting times for a Brownian Motion, starting at $0$ with barriers at $c$ and $−c$ and step size $l=1$

ck1987pd also stated the result in their answer to this question: " [Two-sided hitting time of Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203269/two-sided-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion) ".

I am looking for a reference that derives this probability distribution. Does anyone know of such a reference?

Comment: What is a Brownian motion with step size = 1?

Comment: @JoseAvilez Please see ck1987pd's Question and Response linked above. I used the same terminology as ck1987pd, including the term "Brownian motion". Maybe ck1987pd was referring to a random walk with fixed step size equal to 1, or maybe they were referring to a process where the step size is drawn from a normal distribution with spread = 1. I have been simulating such random walks (step size = 1, OR step size from normal distribution with mu=0, sigma=1, with two absorbing boundaries), and the distribution of hitting times is indeed very close to log-normal, as shown in ck1987pd's Question.

Comment: I think the formula (portrayed as the blue curve in the figure in ck1987pd's Question) could well be correct but I am looking for a reference for that, including a derivation if possible.

(Also: Would be great if @ck1987pd could respond. I would like to ask them directly, but I was not allowed to comment on their questions because I am a new user, and I don't see any email address or way to contact them.)

Comment: Update: For anyone encountering the same problem, the analytic solution was derived by A.W. Jensen, "Random Walks and Applications (Master’s thesis)", University of Montana, 1970, https://scholarworks.umt.edu/etd/8345 which is cited as Ref. 51 in my paper "Simple model of market share dynamics based on clients’ firm-switching decisions", Physica A (2024), https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2023.129489